# Footer width issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem here. I have the following CSS code:

```
body
{
    margin: 0 0 200px; //Same height of the footer
}
div.content
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.main-content
{
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(67, 191, 115, 0.95);
}
```

By this way, in all pages I use:

```
<div class='content'>
    <div class='main-content'>
        //Page content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    //Footer content goes here
</footer>
```

My problem is that the footer is not keeping the width of the page if the resolution is lower than the content, becoming like this:
[image]

I've created this fiddle that shows the problem too: http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/1/
See how the footer don't expand with the table and lets a white space?
How I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using display: table; for div.content?  I guarantee if that was display:block you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @thenetimp because in some pages I have tables with `white-space: nowrap` and if I use `display: block` the table goes out of the content div. And even with `display: block` the white space remains.

Comment: This work correctly in firefox..I can't see that white space ..

Comment: @Dmitriy I'm developing first in computer, not sent to the server yet. But check this fiddle and see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/1/

Comment: @Ferrrmolina please see this fiddle. You will see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/1/

Comment: @Dyan. Works in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I saw the whitespace you were referring to in Chrome. The problem is the `padding: 15px` you have set on `main-content`. I deleted that and it rendered as you're desiring.

Comment: I just noticed it too. The problem is that the table is forced wider than the viewport, so the footer is being sized relative to the viewport. Set a `min-width` on your footer and you'll be set. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/pmb1vbdh/5/. I'd recommend against this kind of design though, unless your target audience will be exclusively using 1550px+ resolutions.

Comment: Hey Man, Updated my answer. Check there and comment with me name.

Comment: @sharf Unfortunately I had tried it. I did not use this "solution" because the width of the page varies according to the content. Note that I did not put in a fixed width in the divs. For example, if I set the min-width to 1500px in a page that has a content of 1000px, I will not have the problem of white space, at least not directly, but empty 500px will dirty the layout pushing the content to the left and removing it of the center of page.

Comment: @GopsAB I need to use `display: table` because of `white-space: nowrap`. Anyway, removing it did not solve the problem. If the resolution is lower than the content, the problem remains.

Comment: @Dyan Then unfortunately, I don't think you can fix this problem without JavaScript. I'd recommend re-evaluating your design, so that you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works. Check this.

```css
div.content
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.main-content
{
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(67, 191, 115, 0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
    <div class='main-content'>
        //Page content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    //Footer content goes here
</footer>
```

**EDIT** for comments in others' answer;

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `right: 0;` to your CSS instead of `width: 100%`:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gops AB is right. Your code is correct.

Comment: I've fiddled with the jsfiddle a bit and here's what I got:
http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/8/

See if this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `table` and the `display:table` of `div.content`

Solution, set a class to the table.

**HTML:**

```
   <div class='content'>
    <div class='main-content'>
        <table class="tab">
            <strong>TABLE</strong>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    //Footer content goes here
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    margin: 0 0 200px; //Same height of the footer
}
div.content
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.main-content
{
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(67, 191, 115, 0.95);
}
table .tab
{
    width: 1500px;
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pmb1vbdh/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: you have `table .tab` but there is no `.tab` element nested under table.

Comment: Thats ok, i'll try again.

Comment: Well, the problem is the  `display:table` and `table` element. If he set `display:block`, or `display:inherit` that work correctly.

Comment: I need to use `display: table` because of `white-space: nowrap`. Anyway, removing it did not solve the problem. If the resolution is lower than the content, the problem remains.